# Facebook SDK - logInWithReadPermissions deprecated - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, facebook-login, onactivityresult

This is my code for facebook login in my app.

```
    private fun handleFacebookSignIn() {
        val loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance()
        loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(this, listOf("email", "public_profile"))
        loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
            override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult) {
                println(result.accessToken)
                loginViewModel.facebookSignIn(result)
                toast(getString(R.string.sign_in_success))
                val intent = Intent(requireContext(), HomeActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

            override fun onCancel() {
                // To Do
            }

            override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
                // To Do
            }
        })
    }
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
```

Here logInWithReadPermissions is deprecated, what is the alternative to this?
And also onActivityResult method was deprecated, how can I use facebook login with ActivityResultLauncher?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, both logInWithReadPermissions and onActivityResult methods for Facebook login are deprecated in the latest Facebook SDK for Android.
Here's how you can update your code to use the alternatives:

**Replacing `logInWithReadPermissions:`**

- Use `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithLoginRequest(this,loginRequest)`instead.
- Use You need to create a `LoginRequest` object with the desired permissions. For
  example, for email and public_profile:

**Kotlin**

```
val loginRequest = LoginRequest.Builder()
    .addReadPermissions("email", "public_profile").build()
```

**Handling Login Results with `ActivityResultLauncher:`**

- Use `registerForActivityResult` to register a callback for the Facebook login
  activity.
- Replace `callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,data)` with
  your callback:

**Kotlin**

```
 private val facebookLoginLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val loginResult = LoginManager.getInstance().onActivityResult(result.data)
            if (loginResult != null) {
                // Handle login success like in onSuccess method above
            } else {
                // Handle login cancellation or error
            }
        } else {
            // Handle login failure
        }
    }

// In handleFacebookSignIn()
facebookLoginLauncher.launch(Intent(loginManager.createLoginIntent(loginRequest)))
```